# Entity Framework On-The-Fly serialization/encryption of properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, encryption

Is that possible to serialize/deserialize a string property of an Entity by using its getters and setters on access, on save?

There are two main goals I would like to do for string properties.

1-Keep a json serialized string for special, complex or custom column types.

2-Encrypt on saving, decyrpt on access confidential information, i.e. Email address

Is that possible?

If so, do we have a limited usage of linq queries on this entity?

If so, would fetching all records and trigger their decryption/deserialization would work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`SavingChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event to modify the entity right before saving it.

Then use the [`ObjectMaterialized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized.aspx) event to handle when the properties are loaded into the entity.

Obviously, these events could be a little bit of overkill but I think you can have a lot of control and you may not want to attach event handlers every time you use the context.